# Working with multiple class

Tags: jquery

I have two nested divs.

```
<div class="AKM _ana_div">  <div class="AKM  Pazartesi 0830 1229"></div>  </div>
```

I want to trigger a function when mouse enters second div.

I tried this but apparently its not working

```
    $(".AKM").mouseenter(function() {
       if ($(this).attr('class') == "0830") { 
            if ($(this).attr('class') == "Pazartesi") {
               DO THIS
            }
       }
   });
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: `$(this).hasClass('xyz')` You can always look at http://api.jQuery.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".AKM").mouseenter(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();  // <---------add this to stop event bubbling
   if ($(this).hasClass("0830") && $(this).hasClass("Pazartesi")) {
        //   DO THIS
   }
});
```

---

Because `.attr()` method returns you the class names in your code context and you are checking for just one class, so its always gets failed. Instead you have to use `.hasClass()` which returns a `boolean` if something you are looking for is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the mouseenter event handler directly to the element(s) you want:

```
// match element(s) with classes AKM, 0830 and Pazartesi
$(".AKM.0830.Pazartesi").mouseenter(function() {
    ...
});
```

*Note*: You can do this in a cleaner way using data attributes and using the class attribute for just styling.